# JQuery call multiple functions inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my relevant code:

```
var dropdown = {
  init: function() {
    $(".dropdown").click(".dropdown", dropdown.openDropdown, dropdown.secondFunction);
  },  
  openDropdown: function() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I call multiple functions on the `click` event?  I added what I tried to do above.

**EDIT**:

So this is my new code with your guys help, and I can confirm both functions are being called because when I put alerts in they both trigger, but for some reason the code inside `openDropdown` right now isn't working.  Is it because my `$(this)` references are off or something?

```
var dropdown = {
  init: function() {
    $(".dropdown").click(".dropdown", function() { dropdown.openDropdown(); dropdown.closeDropdowns(); });
  },
  openDropdown: function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").show();
    $(this).addClass("open");
  },
  closeDropdowns: function() {
    //$(".open").removeClass(".open");
    //$(".open").children(".dropdown-menu").hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: `$(".dropdown").click(".dropdown", ...);` isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function () {
  dropdown.openDropdown();
  dropdown.secondFunction();
});
```

If you want `this` inside of `openDropdown` and `secondFunction` to be the element you would need to use `.call`.

```
var dropdown = {
  init: function() {
    $(".dropdown").on("click", function () {
      // The call makes `this` the element in the functions...
      dropdown.openDropdown.call(this);
      dropdown.secondFunction.call(this);
    });
  },  
  openDropdown: function() {
    console.log('openDropdown', this);
  },
  secondFunction: function() {
    console.log('secondFunction', this);
  }
};

dropdown.init();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bill... I've never heard of that `.call` function, I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
var dropdown = {
  init: function() {
    $(".dropdown").click(".dropdown", function(){ this.openDropdown(); this.secondFunction()});
  },  
  openDropdown: function() {
...
  }
}
```

Comment: So will the `.dropdown` piece inside the `click` handler be passed to both functions?

Comment: on click 'this' will be element that event was invoked so yes '.dropdown'

Comment: Wouldn't `this` be the `.dropdown` element and not the `dropdown` variable?

Comment: Yeah-- I'm confused what `this` is and also what the `.dropdown` being passed in the click event is.  Sorry...

Comment: `this` in the click event is the element. `this` in the scope of `init` would be `dropdown` itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dropdown = {
  init: function() {
    $(".dropdown").click(".dropdown", function() {dropdown.openDropdown(); dropdown.secondFunction(); 
  });
  },
  openDropdown: function() {
     // first function callback
       },
  secondFunction: function()   {
    // second call back 
  }
};

dropdown.init();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/foqez/1)**